# C# combine 2 events in one method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am relatively new to programming, as you will soon see...
I have 2 events, which execute the same code. I currently have the following pseudo code for a datagridview:

```
private void dgv_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)  
{
   string abc = "abc";
}

private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)  
{
   string abc = "abc";
}
```

Is there a way to combine this into one event? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just have one method and map it to two events?

```
private void dgv_CellEvent(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string abc = "123";
}

// In the event mapping

dgv.CellEnter += dgv_CellEvent;
dgv.CellClick += dgv_CellEvent;
```

Comment: Seems like the most concise, "correct" way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Well the quick answer is yes. Put the guts of the methods in its own method and then just have the onclick event call that method. This will give you only one place to update code should it need to change.

There are a 100 different ways to do this, and this is prob the easiest.

So create something like this:

```
protected void MyNewMethod()
{
    string abc = "123";
}
```

and then your other methods will just call it like this:

```
private void dgv_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
    MyNewMethod(); 
}

private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
    MyNewMethod(); 
}
```

## Option 2

Just call the same method from the markup. You really only need one of those methods and the event in the markup can call the same one.

Comment: Regarding Option 2, the question seems to be related to Windows Forms, which doesn't have markup.

Comment: Ah... sorry i missed that.  it still applies just select the control and bring up the properties window and then select the event "tab". and you can just select the same event from the drop down.

Comment: I consider this "the right way to do it."
One benefit of doing it this way is that if the events have different signatures, you can still call MyNewMethod().

Answer (score 2):

In the property window (using C# Express) you can select event handlers in a drop-down, or manually type the name of a method. The signature just has to match. I'm assuming that this is the same in VS.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to do this:

```
private void dgv_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
    dgv_CellClick(sender, e); 
}

private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
    string abc = "abc"; 
}
```

There is code automatically generated by the IDE that wires up your events though, and you could modify this so they both hook up the same event handler, but I don't like messing with generated code.

In ASP.NET or WPF, your data grid or similar has a property that determines the name of the event handler, so you could just point them both to that.

If you were programming in VB.NET instead of C#, you could just write one method and use the Handles keyword to say that this one method handles both events.

Comment: ...or you could refactor the contents of the event handlers into another method, and have both event handlers call that method.

Comment: Beat me to the answer by 3 seconds :)

Comment: @mlevit - I really took and chance and edited it once after submitting too!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
private void dgv_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string abc = "abc";
}

private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dgv_CellEnter(sender, e);
}
```

That way when you either Click or push Enter it will run the same method.

Thanks

Comment: Its probally best to have an intermediary method instead of calling the event handler of a different control