# How can I insert two OnClick event handlers into an .ascx user control?

Tags: asp.net, events, onclick, ascx

Bearing in mind I have started a new job which demands I use Umbraco and `ASP.NET` - platforms/languages I've only been toying with for 2 days and am a total noob at - I have a query regarding inserting a `Google Analytics` event tracking code into a line of an `.ascx` file.

Here goes: I've drilled down into the specific line I'm required to insert a `.gaq` tracking code into; it's an onclick handler that corresponds to a submit button on a contact form. The line is:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Page3NextButton" OnClick="Page3NextButton_Click" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="btnSubmit floatRight">
<span>Submit</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I'd like to add an event tracker to that OnClick property in the form of `"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Volunteer', 'Submit', 'Volunteer Signup'])"` and set up a relevant Event menu in GA. Only thing is, I don't know how to add the code into the existing OnClick setup - it's not a case of separating the two with a semi-colon, as I could do with `JavaScript` entries in normal HTML (eg, `onclick="blah(); dah();")`.

Anyone able to tell me how to set two event handlers in one `OnClick` property in `ASP.NET`? If I sound murky on this it's because this language is extremely new to me.

Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242314/c-sharp-combine-2-events-in-one-method hope this may help you

Answer (score 3):

Use OnClientClick which is used to run JavaScript Before the page posts back.
Something like:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Page3NextButton" OnClick="Page3NextButton_Click" OnClientClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Volunteer', 'Submit', 'Volunteer Signup'])" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="btnSubmit floatRight">
<span>Submit</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Another solution would be to do:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), ="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Volunteer', 'Submit', 'Volunteer Signup'])", true);
```

in the codebehind eventhandler for the click. This will output the script so that it is run when the page is loaded by the browser.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As you mention you need one more click event for Google Analytics only.

I far as I know, Google Analytics event tracking code is in javascript. So, in this scenario, you can use `OnClientClick` event of LinkButton for Google Analytics click event handling. as :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Page3NextButton" OnClick="Page3NextButton_Click" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="btnSubmit floatRight" OnClientClick="gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Volunteer', 'Submit', 'Volunteer Signup'])"></asp:LinkButton>.
```

This should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnClientclick property of the button and use Javascript function to push the code.

Comment: Cheers for the replies everyone - I'm back at work in 2 days, will implement the OnClientClick method, and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks one and all. I've inserted the code - now I guess I wait. I can't see the category, action or label showing up in my GA account, but I have heard that Analytics takes a while to update - or will someone actually have to trigger the event first for the event tracking to fire?

Comment: which scenario did you implement?